# Is there any way to modify App_Code in an ASP.NET application without losing session state?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

We have an ASP Web-Forms site that we update frequently.

However, any time we modify any classes stored in the App_Code folder, this causes an App Pool Recycle and loses all of our session state, causing our users to be logged out.

This means that any time we need to make changes in app code it needs to be around 2:00 in the morning to minimize user impact.

Now, since I value my sleep I was wondering if there is any workaround for this behaviour?

I've tried switching the application to use StateServer mode for Session State.

This seems to work as long as the class being changed is not currently in use.
However if the class is in use it results in every-bodies session being lost.

What is best practice in this case for a heavily used website?

Am I condemned to late nights every time we need to fix a bug in our classes?

Thanks in advance for any response...

Answer (score 2):

You will need sessionState setting cookieless="false" in addition to mode="StateServer".

In addition you need a fixed machine key, so a recycle won't generate a new machine key but uses the same key. If a new key is generated all previous sessionIds can't be decrypted, so the link to the sessionState is lost.

Check https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755177(WS.10).aspx for how to configure/generate a machine key.

This is an example from msdn, so don't use this in production, but generate your own key:

```
<machineKey 
validationKey="32E35872597989D14CC1D5D9F5B1E94238D0EE32CF10AA2D2059533DF6035F4F" 
decryptionKey="B179091DBB2389B996A526DE8BCD7ACFDBCAB04EF1D085481C61496F693DF5F4" 
/>
```

In the end you need something like this in your Web.config or your Machine.config if you want to set the same key on machine level.

Comment: Hi Dacker, Thanks for your response, I just tried setting up fixed machine keys but I still get the same behavior as before. When running on a test server, if I am not actually executing any code (like saving or loading information from the database) I can change app_code without losing state. However if the server is in the middle of processing a postback when the change occurs it ends up losing all state for all users. As the site I am working on is rather frequently used it is more likely than not that a postback will be occurring at any given time during the day.

Comment: I could live with just losing state for the user causing the postback, but unfortunately the server loses all state. It's like the stateserver gets reset or something...

Comment: I have never used StateServer but have always preferred storing the session data myself (created the solution when there was no StateServer). Check whether the sessionId's persist through recycles. If so, you should be able to get the data back if you store it in database (yourself) since the sessionId is still known.